# How much profit can you get if you make a product?

Tags: halal-haram, business

I have an idea to make my own halal company. I am, however, worried about the price range for my product.

I want to make energy shots, with all organic and non-GMO ingredients (ingredients which have been proven to give energy): It takes about $1.00-$1.20 to make each bottle of energy shots. I was thinking since my ingredients are high quality (exotic herbs) that I should place a price between $2.10-$2.60 for each bottle on the market. There is lots of competition and I think that's somewhere near the middle for an energy shot.

Is there an Islamic limit to how much profit I can make on such a product? If so, is my plan acceptable? I need guidance since I don't want a haram profit and I don't want the displeasure of Allah.

Comment: what sort of energy drink are you making bro? Give us the name so that we all can buy it. And please make sure the ingredients are halal.

Comment: Well, I'm still in the process of make my energy shots. And the ingredients are going to be all herbal. I'll give you one of the herbs, Alfalfa (crazy cool herb). Alfalfa give you energy. So, I will definitely make sure all the ingredients are halal (No marijuana).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you sell it at higher prices, it will still be Halal. But that's not recommended by Islam. Although merchants are allowed to make as much profit as they want(even 1000% or more), it is best to keep the price at a just level because higher prices can affect your sales.

Or if you have two customers, person X and person Y. And you know X to be wealthier than Y, then you can give Y a discount(or charge X more), adjusting your profits accordingly. Which is also acceptable.

So if you think that the current price is normal, then its good.

Answer (score -1):

You can make as much profit as you want but you should not tell lies in your business and be afraid of Allah.

Comment: Answers here are expected to be complete and comprehensive; just telling people to go somewhere else to know what to do is just not helpful here.